# Reset Blender Scene

Tags: animation

I am new to Blender and have never done any 3D animation or scene before.

I've created this wrecking ball scene after a tutorial.

[themightylc.bplaced.net/WreckingBall.blend](http://themightylc.bplaced.net/WreckingBall.blend) (4 MB)

Problem is, it won't animate anymore when I start the animation with Alt-A. The timeline "ticks" but everything stays in place. 
I have done nothing but the modeling, changing physics and running the Animation. No idea how or why to use keyframes. Could that be the mistake? Did I ruin this file somehow? If i can't "reset" this, please tell me what i have done wrong to avoid this in the future.

Thank you

Comment: I started over and the same thing happened again :( - I wanted to make the "bottom plane" shorter. After that edit the animation bugged out. I DID NOT SAVE the file and just reloaded it instead. Now it is stuck again at the first frame and nothing happens when i start the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear the physics cache may be the issue. You can either set the start frame to 1 and play, then set it back to 40 or you can re-bake the simulation. In the Rigid Body Cache settings you will find buttons to "Bake All Dynamics" and "Update All To Frame", either will get things running again.

[image]